# Reference Error: LocalStorage not defined - NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, next.js

I am trying to get the access and refresh tokens from my localstorage, but whenever I try it gives me 500:Internal Server Error and returns LocalStorage is undefined.

I looked around and found that LocalStorage does not get rendered with a component and hence the problem.

How will I get the tokens and use them here?

```
const getRefreshToken = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem("refresh_token") //this returns the error
}

const refreshAuthLogic = failedRequest => axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/token/refresh`, getRefreshToken()).then(tokenRefreshResponse => {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', tokenRefreshResponse.data.token);  //maybe these will cause error too, I am not sure.
    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', tokenRefreshResponse.data.refresh_token);
    failedRequest.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + tokenRefreshResponse.data.access_token;
    return Promise.resolve();
});

createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuthLogic);

const getAccessToken = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem("access_token") //this returns the error
}

const authAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`
    }
})

authAxios.interceptors.response.use(createAuthRefreshInterceptor)

export {authAxios}
```

Comment: Is this code running in a browser? It is a browser thing, not server. If you want to use something like that in the backend, there are some npm modules that add the feature.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it is running in a browser. It is to intercept request from the frontend and add an Authorisation header on them, but I can't get the header from the localStorage

Comment: I am not sure how clientside code causes a 500... I think you are running it serverside. Serverside (backend code) has not access to the browser's local storage. If you need to read data on the backend through a request either it has to be passed along or sent as cookie data.

Comment: @epascarello That may be possible, I just tried Axios Instances for the first time, so I am not quite sure. For the server I am running Go-gin server.

Comment: this code is running on the back end; thus, localStorage does not exist on the back end.  You will have to return the refresh token as a cookie like @epascarello said

Comment: @RobertTerrell I understand thank you, which Cookie package should I use since Js-cookie will most likely not work too. Thank you!

Comment: if you're using express cookie parser is probably your best option

Answer (score -1):

So where's your localStorage access error checking in your script?

```
var L='';

if(window.localStorage!==undefined){


 try{ L=window.localStorage;} catch(e){ alert(e); }


} else { alert('LS Disabled'); }
```

With proper error checking you’d know exactly what the problem is, and you wouldn’t have to post your question here.